# What Visual Studio for C?

Tags: c, visual-studio

In Visual Studio Community/Express I can't find any template for C. I can only find C++ and other languages.

What should I download to be able to compile C code?

Comment: Name you source code file `myfile.c` not `myfile.cpp`

Comment: Sometimes a case will arise in which C is bundled into C++. I do not know if that is what you are encountering or not.